# C# Mysql row cannot validate

Tags: c#, mysql, qr-code

I want to validate a QR code from a MySQL database. But the QR code is invalid and I want to access it into my program.

How to validate it?

```
if (decodeStr == null) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("There is no QR Code!");
} 
else 
{
    player.Play();

    ConnectToDatabase();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select Name, LPN From visitors Where password = @password;", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", decodeStr);

    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read()) 
    {
        if(reader["password"].ToString() == decodeStr){
            //this is the problem here..
        }
        MessageBox.Show("he");

        name = reader["Name"].ToString();
        lpn = reader["LPN"].ToString();
    }

    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    //reader.Close();
    videoStream.Stop();
    this.Hide(); // closes the Form2 instance.
    Application.Run(new VisitorData());

}
```

Comment: Whats the Validation Criteria ? Which variable is QR code ?

Comment: Can you make successful connection with database ?

Comment: decodeStr is the variable which stores the QR code. I wanted to show error message if there is no data exist in mySQL

Comment: yes database i can connect

Answer (score 0):

Try code below : Place your connection string inside this code.

```
if (decodeStr == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is no QR Code!");
            }
            else
            {
                player.Play();

                MySqlConnection connection;
                string cs = @"server=server ip;userid=username;password=userpass;database=databse";
                connection = new MySqlConnection(cs);
                connection.Open();

                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
                string SQL = "Select Name, LPN From visitors Where password = @password";
                command.CommandText = SQL;
                command.Parameters.Add("@password", decodeStr);
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("he");

                    name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                    lpn = reader["LPN"].ToString();
                }

                CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
                //reader.Close();
                videoStream.Stop();
                this.Hide(); // closes the Form2 instance.
                Application.Run(new VisitorData());

            }
```

Comment: but i want to verify inside my sql connection. Because all qr code has values. But only some qrcode does match in the database.